# android: detect if the user has canceled an app's installation

Tags: android, installation, google-play

I want to detect if a user has downloaded an Android app, but he clicked the "Cancel" button instead of "Install". Is there a way to detect if the user has canceled the installation of any app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have to be on Google Play and there is no API for this offered by them. It would be nice though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect that, but in the `onActivityResult()` function, you can try to search if the application has been installed in the *PackageManager*, by then you can determine if it has been cancelled or not.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    PackageManager packageManager = this.appContext.getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> apps = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo file = apps.get(i);
        if (file.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)
                .toString().equals("nameoftheapplicationtriedtoinstall")) {
            //then it has not cancelled, if it exist
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way like that.Instead of that u can able identify using particular button with pointer pressed or released.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is something you can detect from your application. I assume only the installer - program that performs the installation - could know this.